# Suppress CA1026 for ASP.NET Core API methods

Tags: asp.net-core, visual-studio-2019

On all of my ASP.NET Core controller API methods I'm getting the CA1026 warning because I'm not checking the parameters passed in. However, I don't think that's necessary to do because either it's part of the route and thus the method won't get called without it, or it's part of the body and I'm checking the `ModelState` being valid before doing anything.

Is there a way to tell Visual Studio 2019 to suppress that message for anything that has the `HttpPut`, `HttpGet`, etc... attributes on it since it's not necessary?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There's a few ways to suppress these warnings, but none of them can do so only for certain methods or certain types of methods only in an automatic way. You can do something like:

```
#pragma warning disable CA1026
[HttpGet]
public IActionResult Foo(string str)
{
    ...
}
#pragma warning restore CA1026
```

But, you'd have to do that on a case by case basis. Any other option, such as `SuppressMessageAttribute` will apply more globally to every method in a particular controller, for example, since it can only go so granular.

Comment: I'm going the route then of adding a Repository for every Controller and making sure the controller *only* has action methods, so I can suppress the warning for the whole file.